# Visual Studio 2022 Unable to set breakpoint on function header due to UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I have recently updated from Visual Studios 2019, to Visual Studios 2022

In the previous version of Visual Studios 2019, I was able to set breakpoints on single line functions, -- but simply putting the breakpoint at the function definition itself -- As shown below:

[image: Visual Studios 2019 Breakpoint on function]

However, after installing to 2022, now this space has been taken up by a new button, that is now blocking my attempt

[image: Visual Studio 2022 Unable to set breakpoint on function]

Is there any way to remove these new added "Implemented Members" button, or to add breakpoint overtop of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under Debug->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced

If you scroll to the very bottom, and uncheck "Combine inheritance margin with indicator margin, you are now able to set breakpoints again at the function level.

[image: Picture of Inheritance Margin setting that can be unchecked]

After unchecking the thing above, now can set breakpoints at the function header, and keep the inheritance margin feature:

[image: Now able to set breakpoint at function header]

Comment: under debug how crazy, these don't just appear during debugging. Possible to remove completely I have no interest.

Answer (score 3):

Pressing F9 while your cursor is on the line in question will set a breakpoint. However, when the inheritance indicator is present, the breakpoint is still obscured and it's difficult to see whether it has been hit.