# Remove up arrow things in margin in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Microsoft, as is their way, have added lots of stuff many people don't want in VS 2022.

I've spent an hour trying to find out how (on Google and in settings) to remove these up arrows from the margin but don't really even know what to search for, or what they're called.

Microsoft should allow you to right click to remove them, settings have loads of options and it's not clear what this is.

How can I remove thanks

(Note, I don't want to put a breakpoint over the top of it so this isn't a duplicate, I want these arrow things gone from the IDE entirely - see details in the answer)

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161324/visual-studio-2022-unable-to-set-breakpoint-on-function-header-due-to-ui

Comment: Thanks, that lead me to a workaround and the answer (just deselect inheritance margin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2022 Unable to set breakpoint on function header due to UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161324/visual-studio-2022-unable-to-set-breakpoint-on-function-header-due-to-ui)

Comment: I enjoyed the question title and opening line, my DuckDuckGo search would not have found this otherwise

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From
[Visual Studio 2022 Unable to set breakpoint on function header due to UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161324/visual-studio-2022-unable-to-set-breakpoint-on-function-header-due-to-ui)

Debug->Options->Text Editor->C#->Advanced

You can deselect 'Combine inheritance margin with indicator margin' to stop that blocking breakpoints, which is in the answer above. However I want to completely remove the arrows.

To do that you can deselect 'Show inheritance margin' to just disable the feature, which is what I want.