# Visual Studio Remove blue markers in vertical scroll bar

Tags: c#, scrollbar, visual-studio-2022

Anyone know how to remove the blue icons in the vertical scroll bar in VS2022 (C#)? I don't actually know what they are for,  But I do know they just clutter the whole scroll bar as to render it nigh on useless (see image)

Note: I am not referring to the 'Inheritance Margin' which also shows inheritance, and sits on the left of the screen. Others on stack overflow have answered how to remove that.  See [Remove up arrow things in margin in Visual Studio 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70430273/remove-up-arrow-things-in-margin-in-visual-studio-2022)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well dang me stupid! This is the OP. They are spelling mistake markers... and the way to remove them is to spell correctly!  Never my strong suite. I still have recurring nightmares about my high school English teacher some 30 years later.

...Or turn off the spelling checker in Edit/Advanced/Toggle Spell Checker